# Some confusion over Numpy + Scipy + matplotlib Spectrum Analyzer code

Tags: python-2.7, audio, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I've been attempting to understand the code at the bottom of http://www.frank-zalkow.de/en/code-snippets/create-audio-spectrograms-with-python.html, though sadly I haven't been getting anywhere with it. I don't think I'm expected to understand most of the code, as I have limited experience with FFTs, but unfortunately I'm also having trouble understanding how the graph is generated. I'm also getting very limited progress from a trial-and-error approach, due to the fact that my computer lags heavily and because of the relatively long time it takes for a graph to be generated.

With that being said, I need a way to scale the graph so that it only displays values up to 5000 Hz, though still on a logarithmic scale. I'd also like to understand how the wav file is sampled, and what values I can edit in order to take more samples per second. Can somebody explain how both of these points work, and how I can edit the code in order to fulfill these requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, this code is by me so gladly help you understanding it. It's maybe not best practice and there may be several ways to improve it – suggestions are welcome. But at least it worked for me.

The function `stft` does a standard [short-time-fourier-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) of an audio signal by the help of the [`numpy strides`](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides). The function `logscale_spec` takes an stft and scales it logarithmically. This is maybe a bit dirty and there must be a better way to do it. But it worked for me. `plotstft` is the function that finally reads a wave file via [`scipy.io.wavfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html), combines the prior two functions and makes a plot with [`matplotlibs imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow). If you have a mono wavefile you should be able to just call `plotstft("/path/to/mono.wav")`.

That was an overview – if I should explain some things in more detail, just say so.

To your questions. To leave out some frequencie values: You can get the frequencies values of the fft wih `np.fft.fftfreq(binsize, 1./sr)`. You just have to find the index of of your cutoff value and leaving this values of the stft.
I don't understand your second question... You can have a look of all samples of your wavefile by:

```
>>> import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
>>> x = wav.read("/path/to/file.wav")
>>> x
(44100, array([4554752, 4848551, 3981874, ..., 2384923, 2040309,  294912], dtype=int32))
>>> x[1]
array([4554752, 4848551, 3981874, ..., 2384923, 2040309,  294912], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I tried scaling the values that np.fft.fftfreq(binsize, 1./sr) took, though it only seemed to scale the tickmarks and not the graph itself. I also tried modifying freq to go up to the cutoff value, but there were errors. However, I did take the hint that freqs needed to be modified somehow, so after a bit of fiddling with the code I found timebins, freqbins = np.shape(ims)[0], np.shape(ims)[1]*hzScale for some ratio hzScale resulted in the desired graph. Sadly, the resolution was terrible (http://puu.sh/8fXzN.jpg); is there any way to improve this, or am I taking the wrong approach? (Thanks)

Comment: Oh, sorry! It just occurred to me that the graph was exact; the wav file I fed the program wasn't a sine wave, so I should've figured that there was to be some general inaccuracy. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Ah; never mind. Apparently I was right on my first guess as to how the program worked, and I didn't think of editing the binsize parameter, which was causing all of the trouble. Apologies for all of the poorly thought out questions, and thanks again.